# How to change faces of org-mode links depending on the link type?

Tags: org-mode, faces, hyperlinks

Org-mode offers a variety of different link types ([http], [file], [bibtex], [magit]...). However, they all get the same look defined by the face value for org-link.

Is it possible to e.g. change the background color depending on the type of link? So that http links would have a yellow background and file links a blue one?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and there is probably more then one way to do it... but that's about all I can tell you :) Hopefully someone with more elisp skills then I have can write out a simple minor mode or something.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Org-Mode version 9.x.

Thanks to John Kitchin's answer in [Fontify broken links in org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/fontify-broken-links-in-org-mode), I applied different faces for id-links and file-links with a code similar to this:

```lisp
  (defface org-link-id
    '((t :foreground "#50fa7b"
         :weight bold
         :underline t))
    "Face for Org-Mode links starting with id:."
    :group 'org-faces)
  (defface org-link-file
    '((t :foreground "#ff5555"
         :weight bold
         :underline t))
    "Face for Org-Mode links starting with file:."
    :group 'org-faces)
  (org-link-set-parameters
   "id"
   :face 'org-link-id)
  (org-link-set-parameters
   "file"
   :face 'org-link-file))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make this a comment, but I don't have enough rep so here goes:

Check out this function: org-activate-plain-links (in org.el).

You can modify the function around the 'add-text-properties', doing a match on each link using a cond for instance.
I have student supervision now, but if you don't succeed in doing this, I'll add more information later.

Comment: `org-activate-plain-links is a function alias and interactive for ignore, defined in subr.el.gz. This command is obsolete since 9.0; use ignore instead. `

Comment: `org-activate-links` is the new function.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/651d24df5f52bb3f0d31c71ebdb604ce356fe674/org-ref.el#L484

I use that code to change the appearance of links in org-ref using font lock at 
https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/651d24df5f52bb3f0d31c71ebdb604ce356fe674/org-ref.el#L742