# Fontify broken links in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, org-link

If I create a bad `[[file:link]]` or an internal `[[Link]]` that does not exist, I would like to `org-mode` to fontify this using `org-warning` face. How can I get this done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In org-9 it might be as simple as this for file links:

```
(org-link-set-parameters
 "file"
 :face (lambda (path) (if (file-exists-p path) 'org-link 'org-warning)))
```

For internal links I don't know an easy way to do it.

Comment: Thanks John! This works great. Is there any way to auto-update this, so that once the file is created, the color changes?

Comment: Not really. It will change the next time it is refontify.  If you change the line or refontify the buffer it should change color I think.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to limit the checking to local files? Emacs shouldn't try to connect to remote files because of this.

Comment: What does a remote file path look like? You can probably match it with a regexp in a conditional expression.

Comment: There is `file-remote-p`, which seems to do the job. I've modified  your code in the following way: `(org-link-set-parameters
 "file"
 :face (lambda (path) (when (not (file-remote-p path))(if (file-exists-p path) 'org-link 'org-warning))))
`