# Org file: Change color of links if they point to a non-existing file/directory

Tags: org-mode, org-link

**Is it possible to have Org-mode links change color if the file/directory they're pointing to does not exist?**

I use the Leuven Theme, and links are displayed in blue. I'd like links to be displayed in red if they point to a non-existing directory. In the following snippet, for example, the first link would be displayed in blue, and the second in red:

```
[[file+emacs:/home/user/existing][This directory exists!.]]
[[file+emacs:/home/user/nonexisting][This directory does not exist!.]]
```

The reason is that I have project directories where the access is shared with other users. Sometimes they rename files and my org documents end up having invalid links. I'd like to have some sort of visual feedback to detect these issues as soon as they appear.

Comment: This is possible with Org-mode 9. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33078/12336 for some inspiration.