# Troubleshooting "Match data clobbered by buffer modification hooks"

Tags: debugging, hooks

When running `bibtex-reformat` I get `Match data clobbered by buffer modification hooks`. I know according to the post [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38862/14853) that one of my [change hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html) is clobbering the match data. In fact, when I set `inhibit-modification-hooks` to `t`, I don't get the error anymore.

I am trying to figure out the culprit for this error. I tried removing all the hooks from `after-change-functions`, `before-change-functions` and `first-change-hook` and set back `inhibit-modification-hooks` to `nil`, but then the error comes back. Evidently, there's a change hook that is running which I don't know.

Is there another way of hunting down the culprit? Or somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: Did you try setting `debug-on-error` to `t` and checking the backtrace to see what caused the problem?

Comment: Yes, but that just shows an error inside `bibtex-reformat` not where the match data was clobbered.

Comment: Load the source file (`*.el`, not `*.elc`) that defines `bibtex-reformat`. Then use `M-x debug-on-entry bibtex-reformat` and step through the debugger. That can help, if you pay attention and test the `match-data` from time to time using `e`. Also, be sure to start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, to remove any of your init file from the search for the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to do that but it’s not clear where the match data is being clobbered. Only that it’s being clobbered when ‘bibtex-reformat’ changes the buffer. Running with ‘emacs -Q’ does not show the error, but I would like to understand what in my setup is clobbering the data (hopefully using a better method than binary-search-commenting my huge init file). I am surprised that when setting all change hooks to nil the match data is still corrupted but it’s not when ‘inhibit-modification-changes’ is set. Am I missing a change hook?